# Firefox CORS failure with express node server

Tags: node.js, express, firefox, cors

I'm using Express.js with the CORS middleware. I'm getting very strange behavior on Firefox v73.0.1 (64-bit)

Clean firefox profile... so nothing is cached.

1. I try a direct request to http://localhost/search?q=AMZN, I get results as expected.
2. I open my webapp which is running on localhost:3000. All of these requests are not using TLS/SSL.
3. I get "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/search?q=AMZN. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)." when it tries to reach out to the API server backend.
4. I refresh the other tab where I was accessing localhost directly (same request which succeeded before), and I get a "connection reset".

Chrome does not do this...

I have been looking at wireshark and Firefox simply sends a GET request (several of them? Why?? I'm only making one), sends the headers and such, then it is followed by connection reset.

Sounds like node is doing something wrong? Or I dunno.

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const util = require('util');
const app = express();
const port = 80;

var cors = require('cors')

var copts = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
      console.log('yeah');
    // allow all
    callback(null, true);
  }
}

const SEARCH_URL = 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/%s.json';

app.get('/search', cors(copts), (req, res) => {
```

The "yeah" part never is hit at all.

Very simple clientside code.

```
return fetch(BACKEND_URL + uri).then(response => {
```

Tried removing CORS middleware and added these headers, based on examining github's cross-browser request-response in chrome

```
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.header('Vary', 'Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Accept-Encoding');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

I didn't really have the options handler captured so maybe this didnt matter. I found those headers in the GET response.

Comment: Where did you add the calls to `res.header`? You might need them in both the OPTIONS request and the GET request sent from the browser. Regarding the OPTIONS request, checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS - scroll to "Functional overview"

Comment: #1 Is your web (localhost:3000) consuming with ajax your backend? , #2 try to use another port instead  80 in your backend. #3 or try to use firefox without plugins https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode

Answer (score 5):

It might be possible that the node server get crashed on an invalid reqeust and hence you are getting the reset error.

With cors package:

You need to add `optionsSuccessStatus` property in the  `cors` options for some legacy browsers. And `OPTIONS handler` To enable pre-flightin requests.

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const util = require('util');
const app = express();
const port = 80;
var cors = require('cors')
var copts = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        console.log('yeah');
        callback(null, true);
    },
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.options("*", cors(copts));
const SEARCH_URL = 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/%s.json';
app.get('/search', cors(copts), (req, res) => { });
```

With headers.: 
You are missing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the response `headers`, you need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header in the response header to allow the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Try this.

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const util = require('util');
const app = express();
const port = 80;
var cors = require('cors')
var copts = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        console.log('yeah');
        // allow all
        callback(null, true);
    }
}
const SEARCH_URL = 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/%s.json';
app.get('/search', (req, res) => { 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.status(200).send("Ok")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, FireFox removes the request header from ajax to a `http` url, but works fine with `https`

Answer (score -1):

Have you updated your front end package.json file with the following?

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:[your port here]/",
```

Answer (score -1):

try assigning CORS to the express server like so:

```js
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```